# how to calculate $\int\limits_{|z| = 2} \frac{z^4dz}{z^4+1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

The original integral is:

$$\int\limits_{|z| = 2} \frac{z^4dz}{z^4+1}$$

It is seen that integration area is a circle with radius 2, the integral has 4 different poles and can be solved as $z = \sqrt[4]{-1}$ (I can calculate it easily by the formula, know that $\arg = \pi$  ).

But, by theory, to calculate such integrals, the power of a denumerator has to be at least two degrees lower than numerator's one, but what to do if they are equal?

Answer (score 3):

Since $\int_{|z|=2}1dz=0$ and $\frac{z^4}{z^4+1}=1-\frac1{z^4+1}$,
$$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{z^4dz}{z^4+1}=-\int_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{z^4+1}$$

Comment: only one question to clarify, why do actually $$\int\limits_{|z| = 2} 1 dz = 0$$

should not it be $z$ ?

Comment: @M.Mass It's a definite integral

Comment: @zhw but what would be its  limits? lower one is 0, but what about opper one?

Comment: @M.Mass It's a contour integral. Just use the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can write our integral as: $$I = \int_{|z|=2} 1\, dz - \int_{|z|=2} \frac{1}{z^4+1}\, dz$$ All the poles of the function $z^4+1$ are in $|z|=2$, so if the roots are $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$, the residue at any one point can be found by: $$\text{ Res }_{z = z_i} f(z) = \frac{1}{(z^4+1)’}\bigg \lvert_{z=z_i} = \frac{1}{4z_i^3}$$

Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: @M.Mass Using the parametrization $z=2e^{i\theta}\implies dz=2ie^{i\theta}\, d\theta$, we get, $$I =\int_{0}^{\pi}2ie^{i\theta}\, d\theta$$ Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Note that, for $R>2$, the function
$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{z^4+1} $$
has no pole in $D=\{z|\ 2\le |z|\le R\}$. Therefore
$$\int_{|z| = 2} \frac{z^4dz}{z^4+1}=-\int_{|z| = 2} \frac{dz}{z^4+1}=-\int_{|z| = R} \frac{dz}{z^4+1}.$$ 
But
$$ \bigg|\int_{|z| = R} \frac{dz}{z^4+1}\bigg|\le\int_{|z| = R}\frac{1}{|z|^4-1}|dz|=\frac{1}{R^4-1}2\pi R\to0 $$ 
as $R\to\infty$. So
$$\int_{|z| = 2} \frac{z^4dz}{z^4+1}=-\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{|z| = R} \frac{dz}{z^4+1}=0.$$